How would Hegel's view on the so-called mind-body problem be categorized today?
There are many attempts today at solving the mind-body problem, and these views can fall into many categories, like compound substance dualism, cartesian dualism, neutral monism, panpsychism, idealism, physicalism etc...
So my question is how would Hegel's view on this issue be accurately characterized using contemporary categories ? Although idealism seems to be adequate at first, he certainly was no subjective idealist like Berkley and doesn't reduce everything to mental phenomenas.
So how would you view it ?

According to the commentaries like Robert Stern or Terry Pinkard, the Hegel's view on the mind-body problem can be categorized today as a form of idealism, particularly a variant often referred to as "absolute idealism." He posited that reality is a dynamic interplay of mind (or spirit) and matter, ultimately seeing them as interconnected rather than fundamentally separate. Hegel emphasized that the development of self-consciousness and the unfolding of the Absolute are central to understanding this relationship.
Today, his perspective might be discussed in the context of philosophical discussions about the nature of consciousness, the role of the mind in shaping reality, and the critique of dualism.
